# Page visibility event not stability fired in Vue PWA

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, firebase-authentication, progressive-web-apps

I'm building a Vue PWA with Firebase authentication. The web app will listens Firebase's `onAuthStateChanged` event on App first loaded to automatically sign the user in and save his `ID token` for API requests latter, by invoke Firebase's `getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true)`.

Beside that, I also utilize Page Visibility API to reload the Web App after 5 minutes hidden (to get new `Firebase ID token` if the old one has expired).

On my Android phone, I visit my web app URL on Chrome, then add icon to home screen and make all test cases by access the web app thru that icon.

Here is the test case: after sign in and using the web app normally, I click Home button to hide the web app, then after ~10 minutes, I recall the app from background state, the web app was auto-reload successfully then I could continue using it as normal. The problem is, if I recall the app from background after a long time (~6 hours), the web app do not auto-reload then I don't have new `Firebase ID Token` of the user, as a result I get `Token Expired` error when making API request to get user profile...

I need to findout a reliable way to trigger `autoLogin()` function, so users don't need to re-login every time when they come back using my WebApp.

Here are skeleton code base:

**main.js**

```
const unsubscribe = fibAuth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    store,
    template: '<App/>',
    components: { App },
    created () {

      // Firebase auto login
      if (user) {
        store.dispatch('autoLogin', user)
      }

      // Reload after a duration
      document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function () {
        store.dispatch('appVisibilityHandler', document.visibilityState)
      })

    } // end created()
  }) // end Vue()
  unsubscribe()
})
```

**Vue Store - index.js**

```
async autoLogin ({commit, state, dispatch}, userPayload) {
  commit('SET_APP_LOADING', true)
  try {
    let idToken = await userPayload.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true)
    console.warn('store::autoLogin() - idToken:', idToken)

    let apiResponse = await UsersRepos.getMyProfile(idToken)
    // ... processing apiResponse ...
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('store::autoLogin() - error:', error)
  }
  commit('SET_APP_LOADING', false)
},

appVisibilityHandler (context, statePayload) {
  try {
    const APP_REFRESH_SECONDS_THRESHOLD = 300 // 5 minutes
    if (statePayload === 'hidden') {
      localStorage.setItem('app-hidden-ts', (new Date()).getTime())
    } else if (statePayload === 'visible') {
      let lastSec = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('app-hidden-ts') / 1000)
      let nowSec = parseInt((new Date()).getTime() / 1000)
      localStorage.setItem('app-hidden-ts', nowSec * 1000)

      console.warn('total hidden seconds:', (nowSec - lastSec))
      if (nowSec - lastSec > APP_REFRESH_SECONDS_THRESHOLD) {
        context.commit('SET_APP_LOADING', true)
        // refresh the whole web page
        router.go()
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    alert('appVisibilityHandler error:' + error.message)
  }
}
```

**I really appreciate any guide or clue to overcome the issue. Thank you in advance!**

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication uses ID tokens that are valid for an hour. Calls to `getIdToken()` return this token. The SDK automatically refreshes the ID token in the background, but of course can't recall your `autoLogin` since the authentication state didn't change.

You'll want to attach an [`onIdTokenChanged` handler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#on-idtoken-changed) to detect when the ID token has changed and pick it up.

```
firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in or token was refreshed.
    store.dispatch('autoLogin', user)
  }
});
```

In fact, this **might** *replace* your `onAuthStateChanged` handler, since this also fires when the user signs in.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tested it out by adding code to listen `onIdTokenChanged()` event (the `fibAuth.onAuthStateChanged()` code was untouched, but it still not realiable fired.

Comment: The `onIDTokenChanged` method should fire when the ID token is refreshed, as that's its whole purpose. If that doesn't happen **and** you can [create an MCVE for that](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it would be really good if you could [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/)